# Two openvpn servers on the same machine, route traffic between the two subnets

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn

I have **two openvpn servers** ( one on tcp, one on udp) running on the **same machine - an OPENVZ vps**.

The first **network A** uses 10.10.0.0/24 and it is designed as an intranet.

The second **network B** uses 10.11.0.0/24 and it is designed so that the clients have access to the internet and the A network.

Both networks are configured with the setting client-to-client and I am pushing the routes for the subnets to clients.

The problem I am having : *I want clients from network B to access machines from network A*.

At the moment clients from B can ping 10.10.0.1 , the A gateway, but CAN'T ping 10.10.0.38( for example).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that each computer know the route to the other network.

Use route print to validate.

Use route add 10.11.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.10.0.1 on B in example, and route add 10.10.0.1 mask 255.255.255.0 10.11.0.1 on A to be sure the packet will go back. Only the machine C that run the openvpn software know all the route.

Comment: did that! Still not working ...

Comment: Oh, turn off their firewall from A and B

Comment: it is turned off!
From a client of the B network, i can ping the A gateway and from a A client I can ping the B gateway. 
Viceversa si also true.

Comment: UPDATE: from the machine that runs the openvpn, the vps, can't ping the clients!
The route is like 10.10.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.10.0.2 - this is setup by the openvpn  server. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes, could be, 10.10.0.2 is what gear?

Comment: Edited my first post, did a typo for the route, 10.11.0.0/24 10.10.0.1.. i wrote 10.10.0.0 > 10.10.0.1..

Comment: Make sure client-to-client is turned on, ipv4 forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf is on, and that you have the proper firewall rules if needed. check if the server can reach the clients on the same subnet, if that all is working ok check the traffic with tcpdump or wireshark (what comes in and goes out, or comes in and does not go out.

Comment: I'll check with tcpdump and come back with an update!

Comment: Ok, back! Tcpdump tells me the packages come in(the udp openvpn server )  but they do not go out on the tcp vpn.